# How to distinguish between underdoped and overdoped regime for a high Tc superconductors?

Tags: solid-state-physics, superconductivity

Suppose I have two samples and oxygenate them under the required conditions. Now I find the value of hole concentration using the formula p = 0.16 + 0.11 (1-Tc/Tc,max)^(1/2) or  p = 0.16 - 0.11 (1-Tc/Tc,max)^(1/2) theoretically? Since the value of Tc will be lowered in both cases (from the electronic phase diagram of high Tc superconductors). Is there any measurement from which we ensure that the crystal is underdoped or overdoped?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Experimentally, how will you distinguish between the underdoped and overdoped values for high Tc cuprates?